# Codeigniter SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I got some problems with the following sql statement:

```
$query= $this->db->get_where('navigation', 'linkname IS NOT NULL 
                             AND parent IS NULL 
                             AND type="main" //this doesn't work!!
                             AND ORDER BY sortnumber ASC');
```

How can I add type="main" in a reasonable way into this statement?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `this doesn't work!!!` mean? What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: This looks like a job for STI, but I'm not sure if codeigniter supports activerecord fully.

Comment: @deceze thanks for commenting: "this doesn't work" means without this part   "AND type="main" " the statement works...

Comment: And *how* "doesn't it work"? Errors? Wrong results? The apocalypse?

Comment: Now that's something you should have a professional look at. Preferably a professional prophet or shaman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* the error is that you should only write `ORDER BY`, not `AND ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend splitting the 'where' clause into several statements. It makes it easier to debug and maintain:

```
$this->db->where('linkname !=', null);
$this->db->where('parent =', null);
$this->db->where('type', 'main');
$this->db->order_by('sortnumber', 'ASC');
$this->db->get('navigation');
```